# equality test of two column header of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find the repeated samples in a data frame by their names, and then calculate the averages of them. But first, the equality test of the sample names isn't working either (or the 'concatenating', I'm not sure, because debugging with print() and write.table didn't help.). What am I doing wrong?

my data table has 20531 rows and 1155 columns, I want to get the mean of the repeated columns per row.

my code for the equality tests (the first column header is the 'gene ID', so I skipped dfs[,1] and after the equality test, I try to concatenate the target columns to one data frame):

```
dfs <- as.data.frame(dfs)
for(i in 2:ncol(dfs)) {
  oneOftheSamples <- data.frame(dfs[,i])
  colnames(oneOftheSamples) <- colnames(dfs)[i]
  head(oneOftheSamples)
  wantedcolname <- colnames(oneOftheSamples)
  n <- i
  for (j in n:ncol(dfs)){
    foundcolname <- colnames(dfs)[j]
    if((wantedcolname==foundcolname) & (j!=i)){
      repOftheSample <- data.frame(dfs[,j])
      colnames(repOftheSample) <- colnames(dfs)[j]
      oneOftheSamples <- data.frame(oneOftheSamples,repOftheSample)
    }
  }
}
```

Any tips or comments could be useful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tip would be to share you data next time. And I can't figure out what your loop is supposed to be doing, but based on your post, this is how you could get the mean of the duplicated columns

```
set.seed(1618)
dat <- matrix(rpois(100, 1), ncol = 10)
colnames(dat) <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = TRUE)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat, check.names = FALSE)

#    A B D E A B B C E B
# 1  0 2 0 2 3 1 0 0 3 0
# 2  1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 1
# 3  0 0 2 0 0 1 4 1 3 0
# 4  1 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 1
# 5  0 1 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 1
# 6  1 0 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
# 7  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
# 8  0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
# 9  0 1 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 0
# 10 0 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 1
```

Some of the columns are duplicated more than two times, so I only want the unique ones

```
(dups <- unique(names(dat)[duplicated(names(dat))]))
# [1] "A" "B" "E"
dat.list <- lapply(dups, function(x) dat[names(dat) %in% x])
# list of three
```

I'm guessing you want the row means for each

```
dat1 <- sapply(1:length(dat.list), function(x) 
  apply(dat.list[[x]], 1, mean))
colnames(dat1) <- dups

as.data.frame(dat1)
#      A    B   E
# 1  1.5 0.75 2.5
# 2  0.5 0.75 1.5
# 3  0.0 1.25 1.5
# 4  0.5 0.75 0.0
# 5  0.0 1.00 0.5
# 6  1.0 0.50 1.0
# 7  1.0 0.75 0.0
# 8  0.5 0.50 0.5
# 9  0.5 0.75 0.5
# 10 0.5 0.50 1.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my answer with the describing of my data immediately. I'm completely new to programming in R, but have a little C++ experience, so I may look like a little dummy about R data structures.
Anyway, I understand your code (at least I think), but it executed the same way, as my full script:
"Error in dfs.list[[x]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: sapply -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN -> apply"
I don't think that I try to access the array out of his boundary. I try to figure out what I messed up.

Thank for your reply!

Comment: I don't think you have duplicated column names exactly. If you change replace = TRUE to FALSE above, there are no duplicates, and I can reproduce your error. When you read in data with `read.table` or something similar, and you have duplicated colnames, you need to use `check.names = FALSE`; otherwise, dup cols will be coded as `A, A.1, A.2` etc. What is the length of `dups` or `dat.list` for your data? If it is zero, that is your problem. Also, I just ran the above with a data frame your size, and it finished in a few seconds on my crummy laptop, so you shouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot, I fixed it! I used read.columns instead of read.table (I have to read in specified columns from multiple files), and in this function the 'check.names' argument cannot be set, but now I rewrite my code.